# select data up to a space?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an MSSQL database field that looks like the examples below:

```
u129  james
u300  chris
u300a jim
u202  jane
u5    brian
u5z   brian2
```

Is there a way to select the first set of characters?  Basically select all the characters up until the first line space?

I tried messing around with LEFT, RIGHT, LEN, but couldn't figure out a way to do it with variable string lengths like in my example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can use a combiation of `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` to find the index of the first space, and then grab everything to the left of that.

```
 SELECT LEFT(YourColumn, charindex(' ', YourColumn) - 1)
```

And in case any of your columns don't have a space in them:

```
SELECT LEFT(YourColumn, CASE WHEN charindex(' ', YourColumn) = 0 THEN 
    LEN(YourColumn) ELSE charindex(' ', YourColumn) - 1 END)
```

Comment: @Beth - please be careful with the editing, you wiped out half of my answer.  Suggesting that I add a reference link would have been more helpful.

Comment: Sorry, LittleBobbyTables, didn't know we had competing modifications.

Comment: Good explanation, but you're off by one - this grabs the space as well.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - yeah, I originally had `RTRIM` in there instead, which masked the space, but it got lost in the edit wars. Updating my answer now, thanks!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to mention `YourColumn` twice, which is problematic if `YourColumn` is a result of a computation (such as a result of `RIGHT`)

Answer (score 3):

```
select left(col, charindex(' ', col) - 1)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to mention `YourColumn` twice, which is problematic if `YourColumn` is a result of a computation (such as a result of `RIGHT`)

Answer (score 2):

If the first column is **always the same size** (including the spaces), then you can just take those characters (via `LEFT`) and clean up the spaces (with `RTRIM`):

```
SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(YourColumn, YourColumnSize))
```

Alternatively, you can extract the second (or third, etc.) column (using `SUBSTRING`):

```
SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(YourColumn, PreviousColumnSizes, YourColumnSize))
```

One benefit of this approach (especially if `YourColumn` is the result of a computation) is that `YourColumn` is only specified once.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you sometimes do not have spaces do not want to use the CASE statement

```sql
select REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(YourColumn), LEN(YourColumn) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(YourColumn))))
```

This works in SQL Server, and according to my searching MySQL has the same functions

Comment: How would we do this in the opposite way, as in we want to go from right to left

Answer (score -2):

If space is missing, you can add one

```
SELECT LEFT('YourTextOrColumn',
            charindex(' ',
            'YourTextOrColumn' + ' ') - 1 )
```